Does the proof of the Weak Maximum Principle in Evans use a derivative that may not exist?
Below is the statement of the Weak Maximum Principle from Evans. In the third part (included below), where the maximum occurs at $(x_0, T)$, the author claims that $u_t(x_0, T) \geq 0$. I understand that this inequality must hold since, otherwise, $(x_0, T)$ could not be a maximum. However, the assumptions only require $u \in C^0(\bar{U}_T)$, which means $u_t(x_0, T)$ may not actually exist.
I attempted to extend $u_t$ to $\partial U$, but later realized this was impossilbe. For instance, consider $f(t) = \sqrt{t}$. Clearly, $f \in C^\infty((0,1)) \cap C^0([0,1])$, but $f'(0)$ does not exist.
Given this, I think a more rigorous approach might be to prove the result for all $U_{T-\varepsilon}$ under the same assumptions. Would you agree with this adjustment, or is there something I'm missing here?

Related part of the proof:


$u\in C^2_1(U_T)$ which means $u$ is once continuously differentiable with respect to $t$ and twice with respect to $x$

Also, don’t forget that $U_T=U \times (0,T]$, so it includes when $t=T$
